# Convertir archivo txt a una matriz python

Tags: python

Aun sigo batallando con un proyecto el cual necesito de su ayuda.

Tengo un archivo de .txt que contiene esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito convertirlo a una matriz como esta:

```
matriz_citas =[
    ["lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","viernes"],
    ["7:00am","7:00am","7:00am","7:00am","7:00am"],
    ["8:00am","8:00am","8:00am","8:00am","8:00am"],
    ["9:00am","9:00am","9:00am","9:00am","9:00am"],
    ["10:00am","10:00am","10:00am","10:00am","10:00am"],
    ["11:00am","11:00am","11:00am","11:00am","11:00am"],
    ["1:00pm","1:00pm","1:00pm","1:00pm","1:00pm"],
    ["2:00pm","2:00pm","2:00pm","2:00pm","2:00pm"],
    ["3:00pm","3:00pm","3:00pm","3:00pm","3:00pm"],
    ["4:00pm","4:00pm","4:00pm","4:00pm","4:00pm"],
    ["5:00pm","5:00pm","5:00pm","5:00pm","5:00pm"]]
```

No puedo usar librerías de ningún tipo, encontré otra publicación similar pero el código no funcionó

Usé este código:

```
 with open("Horario.txt", "r") as datos:
    valores = []
    for linea in datos:
        valores.append([str(x) for x in linea.strip().split(",")])
    print(valores)
```

**Pero ese código me crea una matriz diferente y no me deja trabajar en ella:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno sabe como puedo hacerlo y que me quede la matriz a como la necesito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Como las líneas de tu texto ya tienen formato de lista, puedes hacerlo fácilmente utilizando la función [`eval()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval), que convertirá el `string` de cada línea en una lista y luego simplemente lo agregas a tu lista `valores`

Ejemplo completo:

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as datos:
    valores = []
    for linea in datos:
        valores.append(eval(linea))
    print(valores)

    # Para comprobar que es una lista de listas puedes acceder a cada elemento
    print(valores[0][0])
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[['lunes', 'martes', 'miercoles', 'jueves', 'viernes'],
['7:00am', '7:00am', '7:00am', '7:00am', '7:00am'],
['8:00am', '8:00am', '8:00am', '8:00am', '8:00am'],
['9:00am', '9:00am', '9:00am', '9:00am', '9:00am'],
['10:00am', '10:00am', '10:00am', '10:00am', '10:00am'],
['11:00am', '11:00am', '11:00am', '11:00am', '11:00am'],
['1:00pm', '1:00pm', '1:00pm', '1:00pm', '1:00pm'],
['2:00pm', '2:00pm', '2:00pm', '2:00pm', '2:00pm'],
['3:00pm', '3:00pm', '3:00pm', '3:00pm', '3:00pm'],
['4:00pm', '4:00pm', '4:00pm', '4:00pm', '4:00pm'],
['5:00pm', '5:00pm', '5:00pm', '5:00pm', '5:00pm']]
lunes
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te dijeron puedes usar `eval` ya que lo que tienes como resultado es una lista de python válida y al uar `eval` será evaualda como código python. Sin embargo el uso de `eval` no es recomendado, ya que como dije evalúa el string como código python y literalmente se puede hacer de todo.

Para evitar este problema tenemos a la librería `ast` y la función `literal_eval` que es una función mucho más segura, ya que está función solo evalúa string como objetos básicos de python. El código sería así:

###### código adaptado de la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/552898/183782) de @HeytalePazguato

```py
from ast import literal_eval

with open("sample.txt", "r") as datos:
    valores = []
    for linea in datos:
        valores.append(literal_eval(linea))
    print(valores)
    print(valores[0][0])
```

Otra forma sería hacer tu mismo el procesamiento. Lo cual puede ser hecho a base de `replace()` (o mediante expresiones regulares) pero lo veo bastante largo aspi que usaré el método `.translate()` para reemplazar los caracteres en base a su código ASCII.

```py
def procesar_linea(linea: str) -> str:
    return linea.strip().translate({
        91 : "",
        93 : "",
        34 : ""
    }).split(",")

with open("sample.txt", "r") as datos:
    valores = [procesar_linea(linea) for linea in datos]
print(valores)
```

Eso sería todo el código. El único detalle es que aparece un elemento vacío al final de cada arreglo (exceptuando el último) debido a la estructura de tu archivo y al procesamiento de los datos, esto puede ser corregido con otro ciclo `for` que elimine eso. Por ejemplo la siguiente línea resuelve el problema:

```py
valores = [lista[:-1] if not lista[-1] else lista for lista in valores]
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución corta:

```
with open("citas.txt") as citas:
    matriz = []
    for linea in citas:
        campos = linea.strip()[1:-1].replace('"','').split(",")
        matriz.append(campos)

print(matriz)
```

Se lee el archivo linea por linea. Por cada línea:

- Se le sacan los espacios al principio y al final (`strip()`).
- Se elimina el primer; últimos caracter ("[]").
- Se eliminan las cremillas dobles.
- El resultado se separa por las comas.

Asi se obtiene una lista con los elementos de la lista, que se incorporan a la matriz.